# Sqlite table does not show updated data base table when i close the app

Tags: ios, ipad, sqlite, insert

When i first start the app it works fine and also show records which insert new in the app but once i close the app it does not show any record of the sqlite data base it just shows the record which i inserted hardcode form sqlite manager outside of the app.any idea how to fix this issue so that when i close the app it should also show new inserted data.Here is the code for inserting data

```c
- (void) addCoffeePL:(NSString *)dbPath {
    if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "insert into publish(userID,Catgeory,SubCategory,ContentType,ContentTitle,ContentDescription,ContenAddedTime,Size,UserName,organizationCode) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [userID UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [categoryTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [subCategoryTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4, [contentType UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 5, [contentTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 6, [contentDescription UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 7, [contentAddedDateTime UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 9, [userName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 10, [size UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 11, [organizationCode UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
        //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using  sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
        coffeeID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    //Reset the add statement.
    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);

    sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);
}
```

Comment: What code is responsible for closing the database?

Comment: @CL did not added closing the database code without that will not work this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the given below example, Which uses singleton and also MVC pattern for SQLite..it may be more help full to you...

https://www.opendrive.com/files?M182MDY5MDg4X2RadUd5

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
You shouldn't open your database every time you want to use it. Instead create singleton class with your database connection

```
#define kDatabaseFilename @"yourDatabaseName.sqlite"


@implementation DatabaseConnector

+ (DatabaseConnector *)instance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static DatabaseConnector * sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        NSString *pathsToResources = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
        NSString *databasePath = [pathsToResources stringByAppendingPathComponent:kDatabaseFilename];

        NSArray *pathsToDocuments = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [pathsToDocuments objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *newDatabasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kDatabaseFilename];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:newDatabasePath])
        {
            NSLog(@"No database available, copying from bundle");
            if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:databasePath toPath:newDatabasePath error:NULL] != YES)
            {
                NSLog(@"Fail to copy database from %@ to %@", databasePath, newDatabasePath);
            }
        }

        if (sqlite3_open([newDatabasePath UTF8String], &_database) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

then use this function to insert:

```
- (void)addCoffeePL:(YourObject*)yourObject
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    const char *sql = "insert into publish(userID,Catgeory,SubCategory,ContentType,ContentTitle,ContentDescription,ContenAddedTime,Size,UserName,organizationCode) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [yourObject.userID UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [yourObject.categoryTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [yourObject.subCategoryTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [yourObject.contentType UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [yourObject.contentTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, [yourObject.contentDescription UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);    
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 7, [yourObject.contentAddedDateTime UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 8, [yourObject.userName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 9, [yourObject.size UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 10, [yourObject.organizationCode UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement))
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
    }

    sqlite3_reset(statement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 8th parameter

```
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 7, [contentAddedDateTime UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 9, [userName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 10, [size UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 11, [organizationCode UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

change to

```
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 7, [contentAddedDateTime UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 8, [userName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 9, [size UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 10, [organizationCode UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Comment: it does not mean anything i am asking when you insert data using this code it inserts record and shows it but once you close the app record is also vanished